# Information matrix in 3D point cloud registration?

Tags: math, registration, point-clouds, information-theory, open3d

In Open3D library there is a function which calculates the information matrix, it uses 2 clouds, a transformation matrix (output of a registration algorithm) and a distance. I would like to understand the meaning of a information matrix in the context of 3D point cloud registration, for what is it used for?

I know how to calculate it, but just because I read the Wikipedia article. And I read some articles, but there's nothing to guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The derivation of the information matrix comes from **equation 8** in the paper:
*[Robust Reconstruction of Indoor Scenes, CVPR, 2015](http://qianyi.info/docs/papers/cvpr15_loopclosure.pdf)* by ***Choi et***.

Basically it's used for computing the sum of squared distances between all correspondences, and the paper did an approximation to construct the informaiton matrix.

---

By the way, the approximation is also used as ***virtual pair approach*** in a 1996 paper:
*[Multiview Registration for Large Data Sets](http://people.csail.mit.edu/kapu/papers/pulli_3dim99.pdf)* by ***Kari Pulli***. Pay attention to **figure 6** if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by [@Jing Zhao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610131/16362892), the derivation comes from the Robust Reconstruction of Indoor Scenes, but yet a more detailed one can be found on [Observability, Covariance and Uncertainty of ICP Scan Matching](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Francois-Goulette/publication/267515355_Observability_Covariance_and_Uncertainty_of_ICP_Scan_Matching/links/54bfdc5e0cf28a63249ff714/Observability-Covariance-and-Uncertainty-of-ICP-Scan-Matching.pdf) by **Barczyk**, **Bonnabel** and **Goulette**, especially for the transformation linearization parts.